# No ArcGIS Server License found

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, sql-server, arcgis-license-manager, connection

I have attached geodatabase "Riverside" to databases list in MS SQL SERVER 2012 Enterprise edition  :

[image]

After that I created two logins using :

```
   USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [sde] WITH PASSWORD='sde_class', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
CREATE LOGIN [GISADMIN] WITH PASSWORD='gisadmin', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
```

Then  I tried to add a database connection from catalog window within ArcMap ,but the connection failed :

[image]

After that  I went to security folder inside the "Riverside"  I found a user with name "GISADMIN" . I thought I could delete this user and create another user with same name . The deletion failed ,

[image]

my last option was mapping this user"GISADMIN" to the login "GISADMIN" .

```
use RIVERSIDE
go
exec sp_change_users_login 'GISADMIN', 'gisadmin'
go
```

Nothing changed!
I'm using ArcGIS 10.3 running on Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Did you already enable the geodatabase, i.e. run the *Enable Enterprise Geodatabase* tool from ArcMap / ArcCatalog? Adding a new user is in my experience easier to do from within ArcMap: right click on the database connection and select *Administration > Add user*.

Comment: "Add User" works on active connection , it's disable in this case.

Comment: 1) You cannot change the database name when attaching a geodatabase.  2) You will likely need to use sp_change_users_login to de-corrupt the users after the attachment process 3) Be hyper-aware of case sensitivity - I **NEVER** use UPPERcase anything in object naming (not databases, not users, not schemas, not tables, not columns)

Comment: Yeah, you need an active connection using an administrative user to do that. But the database must be geo-enabled first anyway. That is, the SDE tables should be there, as well as the sde user. There must be a valid license set in the database too.

Comment: Yes it's already geo-engabled .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working:

1. Go to "Database Connections" in the catalog window or ArcCatalog.
2. Double click "Add Database Connection" a dialog box will open and authenticate    as Database Administrator "sa" or using your windows authentication is the user part of sysadmin.
3. Click OK, another dialog box will pop up asking you to provide a path to license file give it the path, and then everything will work fine .

Comment: Good to hear - this appears to be a handy shortcut to the method in my answer above

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide your geodatabase with a license to use in an enterprise database environment.

Run the [Create Enterprise Geodatabase](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-enterprise-geodatabase.htm) tool and provide the license or authorization file in order to license your database.

This tool needs to be run even if the database already exists - if it exists you just point it at the existing database and it will authorize it.  If it doesn't exist it would also create it and set up the SDE tables (not applicable in your case).

[image]